# Google traffic overlay + openlayers 3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, openlayers-3

I am trying to integrate a google traffic overlay with the openlayer 3. I am able to aff the google traffic layer, but its coming as a base layer. I want it as a tile layer, so that I can switched that using layer switcher

Comment: Which layer switcher are you using? With these it should be possible https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-layerswitcher, just do now mark the google layer as base layer.